# How to use metalua to autobuild documentation?

Tags: lua, documentation, metaprogramming, documentation-generation

How can I use metalua to automatically build my code's documentation (like doxygen)?

I imagine a syntax like:

```
--> @ARG: a(number) first Number
--> @ARG: b(number) second Number
--> @RET: bool if a was greater than b
--> @RET: number sum of a and b
--> Add a and b while comparing their values
function addcmp(a,b)
  return (a>b),(a+b)
end
```

To create e.g. HTML like:

```
<h1>addcmp</h1>
<i>Add a and b while comparing their values</i>
<h2>Arguments:</h2>
<ul>
  <li><i>number</i> <b>a</b>: first Number</li>
  <li><i>number</i> <b>b</b>: second Number</li>
</ul>
<h2>Returns:</h2>
<ul>
  <li><i>bool</i>: if a was greater than b</li>
  <li><i>number</i>: sum of a and b</li>
</ul>
```

When invoked like:

```
metalua -v sample.mlua -o sample.html --make-doc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [luadoc](/questions/tagged/luadoc). The default doc generation templates are pretty neat and you can run it for all the files in a directory as well.

The [Kepler Project documentation](http://keplerproject.github.io/luadoc/) is a good way of seeing what the results shall look like.

Comment: that's exactly the functionality I was looking for, but I wanted it to be in metalua, so I could also use it for on-the-fly in-application help, but I think that could be "compiled" using luadoc too...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. [LuaDocumentor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/User_Area/LuaDocumentor) understands a language in [comments](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Koneki/LDT/User_Area/Documentation_Language) largely inspired by LuaDoc, which allows Eclipse to autocomplete your code based on typing hints, and allows to generate html documentation.

It happens to be written in Metalua. All those (Metalua and LuaDocumentor) should soon be available as a LuaRocks.